# Prestashop override admin controller tpl file

Tags: overriding, admin, prestashop

im creating a module and would like to override admin controller tpl file. Its admin/theme/controller/orders/_product_line.tpl

I tried to create in module folder: override/controllers/admin/orders and put edited file.

I found a few functions to override, but also it gives me nothing.

If u could share your code or give me advice I would really appreciate it. I can`t find any information about it.

Comment: Did you read [Using helpers to overload a back-office template](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Using+helpers+to+overload+a+back-office+template)?

Comment: Yes, I have read. But If I would like to override from module an existing orders _product_line.tpl file?

Comment: You can't override `_product_line.tpl` from the module directly. You could do it indirectly by overriding `/controllers/admin/AdminOrdersController.php` with `/modules/your_module/override/controllers/admin/AdminOrdersController.php` to load the `_product_line.tpl` that is in your module's directory.